I have problem with finding the equation of AC to DC voltage for three phase five wire rectifier
I am writing a thesis about telecommunication tower.  A problem came up when I examined the power supply. Most telecommunication equipment uses -48V DC and my supervisor wants me to add the equation of the AC to DC rectifier in my thesis. When I searched online about rectifiers, most of them show a derivation to obtain the ripple effect or voltage stability. Can you share where can I find them or answer to this question?
